# combine two lists with same keys

Tags: scala

Here's a quite simple request to combine two lists as following:

```
scala> list1
res17: List[(Int, Double)] = List((1,0.1), (2,0.2), (3,0.3), (4,0.4))

scala> list2 
res18: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,aaa), (2,bbb), (3,ccc), (4,ddd))
```

The desired output is as:

```
((aaa,0.1),(bbb,0.2),(ccc,0.3),(ddd,0.4))
```

I tried:

```
scala> (list1 ++ list2)
res23: List[(Int, Any)] = List((1,0.1), (2,0.2), (3,0.3), (4,0.4), 
(1,aaa), (2,bbb), (3,ccc), (4,ddd))
```

But:

```
scala> (list1 ++ list2).groupByKey

<console>:10: error: value groupByKey is not a member of List[(Int, 
Any)](list1 ++ list2).groupByKey
```

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is [`groupBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]):

```
(list1 ++ list2).groupBy(_._1)
```

If you know that for each key you have exactly two values, you can join them:

```
scala> val pairs = List((1, "a1"), (2, "b1"), (1, "a2"), (2, "b2"))
pairs: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a1), (2,b1), (1,a2), (2,b2))

scala> pairs.groupBy(_._1).values.map {
     |   case List((_, v1), (_, v2)) => (v1, v2)
     | }
res0: Iterable[(String, String)] = List((b1,b2), (a1,a2))
```

Another approach using `zip` is possible if the two lists contain the same keys in the same order:

```
scala> val l1 = List((1, "a1"), (2, "b1"))
l1: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a1), (2,b1))

scala> val l2 = List((1, "a2"), (2, "b2"))
l2: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a2), (2,b2))

scala> l1.zip(l2).map { case ((_, v1), (_, v2)) => (v1, v2) }
res1: List[(String, String)] = List((a1,a2), (b1,b2))
```

Comment: @user1460691 you're welcome. Feel free to accept one of the two answers to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one-liner:

```
scala> list2.map(_._2) zip list1.map(_._2)
res0: List[(String, Double)] = List((aaa,0.1), (bbb,0.2), (ccc,0.3), (ddd,0.4))
```

If you are unsure why this works then read on!  I'll expand it step by step:

```
list2.map(<function>)
```

The `map` method iterates over each value in `list2` and applies your function to it.  In this case each of the values in `list2` is a Tuple2 (a tuple with two values).  What you are wanting to do is access the second tuple value.  To access the first tuple value use the `._1` method and to access the second tuple value use the `._2` method.  Here is an example:

```
val myTuple = (1.0, "hello")   // A Tuple2
println(myTuple._1)            // prints "1.0"
println(myTuple._2)            // prints "hello"
```

So what we want is a *function literal* that takes one parameter (the current value in the list) and returns the second tuple value (`._2`).  We could have written the function literal like this:

```
list2.map(item => item._2)
```

We don't need to specify a type for `item` because the compiler is smart enough to infer it thanks to *target typing*.  A really helpful shortcut is that we can just leave out `item` altogether and replace it with a single underscore `_`.  So it gets simplified (or cryptified, depending on how you view it) to:

```
list2.map(_._2)
```

The other interesting part about this one liner is the `zip` method.  All `zip` does is take two lists and combines them into one list just like the zipper on your favorite hoodie does!

```
val a = List("a", "b", "c")
val b = List(1, 2, 3)

a zip b     // returns ((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
```

Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't combine the lists based on key, it combines them by their index, which in the OPs example happens to correspond to the index

Comment: I believe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293018/1507124 more accurately answers the spirit of the question