# Scala - Join List of tuples by Key

Tags: scala

I am looking for a way to join two list of tuples in scala to get same result than Apache spark gives me using join function.
Example:
Having two list of tuples such us:

```
val l1 = List((1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2))
l1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2))

val l2 = List((1,(1,2)), (2,(2,3)))
l2: List[(Int, (Int, Int))] = List((1,(1,2)), (2,(2,3)))
```

What is the best way to join by key both list to get the following result?

```
l3: List[(Int,(Int,(Int,Int)))] = ((1,(1,(1,2))),(1,(2,(1,2))),(2,(1,(2,3))),(2,(2,(2,3))))
```

Comment: the List.groupByKey may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want do do something like this:

```
val l3=l1.map(tup1 => l2.filter(tup2 => tup1._1==tup2._1).map(tup2 => (tup1._1, (tup1._2, tup2._2)))).flatten
```

It Matches the same Indexes, creates sublists and then combines the list of lists with the `flatten`-command

This results to:

```
List((1,(1,(1,2))), (1,(2,(1,2))), (2,(1,(2,3))), (2,(2,(2,3))))
```

Comment: it works perfectly, but I changed Map-Flatten and I used flatMap function instead of: `val l3=l1.flatMap(tup1 => l2.filter(tup2 => tup1._1==tup2._1).map(tup2 => (tup1._1, (tup1._2, tup2._2))))
`

Answer (score 9):

You can use a for comprehension and take advantage of using the '`' in the pattern matching. That is, it will match only when keys from the first list are the same with the ones in the second list ("`k`" means the key in the tuple must be equal to the value of k).

```scala
val res = for {
  (k, v1)   <- l1
  (`k`, v2) <- l2
} yield (k, (v1, v2))
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: This is a dope one! Any doc to this?

Comment: Fair enough - here it is - https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
val l2Map = l2.toMap
val l3 = l1.flatMap { case (k, v1) => l2Map.get(k).map(v2 => (k, (v1, v2))) }
```

what can be rewritten to more general form using implicits:

```
package some.package

import scala.collection.TraversableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

package object collection {

  implicit class PairTraversable[K, V, C[A] <: TraversableLike[A, C[A]]](val seq: C[(K, V)]) {

    def join[V2, C2[A] <: TraversableLike[A, C2[A]]](other: C2[(K, V2)])
                                                    (implicit canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[C[(K, V)], (K, (V, V2)), C[(K, (V, V2))]]): C[(K, (V, V2))] = {
      val otherMap = other.toMap
      seq.flatMap { case (k, v1) => otherMap.get(k).map(v2 => (k, (v1, v2))) }
    }
  }
}
```

and then simply:

```
import some.package.collection.PairTraversable

val l3 = l1.join(l2)
```

This solution converts second sequence to map (so it consumes some additional memory), but is much faster, than solutions in other answers (compare it for large collections, e.g. 10000 elements, on my laptop it is 5ms vs 2500ms).

Answer (score 0):

Little late. This solution will give you back the original size of l1 and return Option(None) for missing values in l2. (Left join instead of inner join)

```
    val m2 = l2.map{ case(k,v) => (k -> v)}.toMap

    val res2 = l1.map { case(k,v) =>
        val v2 = m2.get(k)
        (k, (v, v2))
    }
```